# Could anybody offer advice on my Axios Post Request?

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I'm trying to post multiple objects from an array to an API using axios, I'm also trying to limit the post requests to 1 per 10 seconds. I have the following code, but it's not giving me anything, no response, error, nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
const axios = require("axios");
const { auth, baseUrl } = require("./connect");
const fs = require("fs");

// POST sample data
function postSales() {
  auth.then(result => {
    let token = result.access_token;

    const data = fs.readFileSync("./temp/converted.json", "utf-8");
    setTimeout(() => {
      data.forEach(sale => {
        axios
          .post(
            `${baseUrl}/sale.json`,
            { sale },
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                scope: `employee:all`
              }
            }
          )
          .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      });
    }, 10000);
  });
}

postSales();
```

Comment: whats in sale,json

Comment: `readFileSync` returns a buffer (?). What do you think `data.forEach` does `?

Comment: ``${baseUrl}/Sale.json`` almost certainly is a mistake. This should be the name of the api endpoint you are `POST`ing to

Comment: @Andrew, no mistake there. It's using a variable to store the base url.

Comment: @DarrylMorley If `Sale.json` is a variable, you forgot to string interpolate it. It should be `${baseUrl}/${Sale.json}`

Comment: @JonasWilms data.forEach iterates through each object in the data array, each object would be 'sale'? I think.. or hope

Comment: @Andrew No, ${baseUrl}/Sale.json equates to https://myapi/Sale.json for example. maybe the 's' should be lowercase :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the advice, managed to figure out my issues from your comment!

Answer (score 2):

`fs.readFileSync` returns a stringified version of your data. You need to `JSON.parse` it.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temp/converted.json", "utf-8");)
```

Using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` sends the operation to the event queue and makes the waiting interval very difficult. Using a `for` loop and using the `async`/`await` syntax is much easier to write and reason about. No `sleep` function exists in javascript, but it's easy to make one yourself.

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
auth.then(async result => {
    let token = result.access_token;
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temp/converted.json", "utf-8");)


    for (let sale of data) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post() // didn't add params, for brevity
            console.log(res)
            await sleep(10_000) // 10 seconds
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Andrew, I literally just set it to parse before reading this and it's running as I type. I like the way you have wrote this, much clearer.